# Can I have a decent game at Fallout Shelter by casualy playing it a few minutes a day?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My question is similar to this one [What happens if I ignore my Fallout Shelter game for two weeks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233263/what-happens-if-i-ignore-my-fallout-shelter-game-for-two-weeks) but I didn"t find an answer there.

I would like to know how much attention does it require to play decently at Fallout Shelter?

From what I have tried for now, by playing a few minutes a day (e.g. in the train home/work, on coffee break...) it does not seem enough as hapiness and health quickly drops and I'm constantly lacking of ressources.

Maybe I took bad decisions, or maybe there is a setting to have different time stretching or auto background play...

Comment: Never had any problems myself. Didn't take long to have max resources, max happiness and then max caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played this game in a few months, but I played it pretty extensively for months after it first came out.

In my experience, it doesn't really matter how long it has been since you last played, except concerning dwellers out exploring, which is addressed in the question you linked.

The game continues consuming resources for a minute or two after you turn it off, and then stops until you turn it back on. As long as your few minutes a day ends with full resource bars, and your resource bars are long enough to run your vault for a couple minutes, then you'll be fine.

The main issue will be your initial explorers, you won't be able to survive a full 24 hours in the wasteland. You'll want to check on them after a few hours, possibly setting an alarm so you don't forget. If you're not playing on survival, you can always just resurrect an explorer that dies. If you do open the game just to check on your explorers, make sure that you pay attention to your resources and get your bars full again before turning it off, otherwise your vault will starve for the few minutes after you turn it back off.